# How to use enum key value in java

Tags: java, enumeration

I want to create an enum class in java 11 with key value
I create a enum like this

```
public enum status{

    ACTIVE("Active", 1), IN_ACTIVE("In Active", 2);

    private final String key;
    private final Integer value;

    Status(String key, Integer value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

the problem that when i do Saison saison.getvalues()
i got like this

```
[
"ACTIVE",
"INACTIVE"
]
```

But i want to got like this

```
[
{
"Key": "Inactive", 
"value":"2"
},
{
"Key": "Active",
 "value":"1"
}
]
```

how can i call my enum tio get a result like this

Comment: You mean when trying to encode as json?

Comment: ` saison.getvalues()` well, there is no `saison` in your question. Also, class names *should* be PascalCase, so `Status` or `Saison`, not `status` or `saison`. Also, is the output supposed to be JSON? If so, you might want to look into specialized tools for that.

Comment: What are you taking about? Java enums doesn't have getValues() method... What is `Saison`?

Comment: thank you so much ur help it's work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing to prevent you from returning a map entry which contains the `key,value` pair.

```
 enum Status {

    ACTIVE("Active", 1), IN_ACTIVE("In Active", 2);

    private final String key;
    private final int value;

    Status(String key, int value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public Entry<String,Integer> getBoth() {
        return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, value);
    }   
}

Entry<String,Integer> e = Status.ACTIVE.getBoth();
System.out.println("Key: = " + e.getKey());
System.out.println("Value: = " + e.getValue());
```

or print the toString() value of the Entry.

```
System.out.println(e);
```

Prints

```
Key: = Active
Value: = 1
Active=1
```

You can also override toString of your Enum and do something like this.

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("\"key\": \"%s\",%n\"value\": \"%s\"",
            getKey(), getValue());
}

System.out.println(Status.ACTIVE);
```

Prints

```
"key": Active",
"value": "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did in this way to return all key and value in list.

```
public enum FileCode {
    AB("AB", "AB description"),
    CD("CD", "CD description"),
    EF("EF", "EF description");

    private final String key;
    private final String value;
    private final KeyValue keyValue;

    FileCode(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.keyValue = new KeyValue(key, value);
    }

    public static List<KeyValue> getAllKeyValue() {
        List<KeyValue> keyValueList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (FileCode f : FileCode.values()) {
            keyValueList.add(KeyValue.builder()
                    .key(f.key)
                    .value(f.value)
                    .build());
        }
        return keyValueList;

    }

    public Map.Entry<String, String> getBoth() {
        return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, value);
    }

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    public static class KeyValue {
        String key;
        String value;

    }

}
```